# Semaphores the output of the following

Tags: semaphore

I wanted to know the output of this program, step by step, please.
 initially, the values are: S1=0 , S2=1 , S3=0, a=1.enter code here

```
p1                  p2                  p3
while(1) {       while(1){             while(1){  
P(S1)            P(S2);               P(S3);
a=2*a;         a=a+1;               P(S3);
V(S3) }        V(S1);               printf("%d\n",a);
                   V(S3) }              V(S2);
```

Comment: We're not here to do your homework.  Nor could we if we wanted to, since you didn't define what P and V are.  And what does any of this have to do with semaphores?

Comment: I agree with Gabe it really looks like homework. You should edit your question if it is not.

Comment: @GabeSechan P and V are the names of the "enter" and "exit" semaphores functions in classical literature.

Comment: no its not homework, it's an exercise from the internet that i was trying to do, but couldn't reach the solution that they give

Comment: @Ivan: so maybe provide a link to the exercice, its solution and explain what you didn't understand in the solution?

Comment: okay http://asc.di.fct.unl.pt/~vad/ASC2/ASC2-0405/extra/exame2.pdf the exercise is the 3rd one,  http://asc.di.fct.unl.pt/~vad/ASC2/ASC2-0405/extra/ex2-ajudas.txt and the solution is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution you have linked is correct.
In informal terms: P blocks while the semaphore == 0 or decrement the semaphore and continues; V increments the semaphore.

At first S1 and S3 == 0, so p1 and p3 are blocked.

p2 is the only one that can run. It increments a (== 2) and increments S1 and S3. It cannot continue because S2 is now 0.

p3 can only do one step, because after the first P call, S3 == 0 again.

p1 is the only process that can do work. It doubles a (== 4) then unblocks S3. It cannot continue because S2 is 0 again.

Now p3 is the only one that can run. It prints **4**. Then unblocks p2.

Notice the situation is exactly the same as at the beginning of the problem (except a == 4 now). So each cycle runs exactly the same way: p2 increments a, p1 doubles a, p3 prints a. Repeat.

Hence printed values are **4, 10, 22, 46...**

Comment: i didnt understand how p3 entered the printf zone, because there are always 2 P(S3) there, shouldnt it get blocked over and over?

Comment: There are two P(S3), so it needs two V(S3) to enter (given that S3 == 0 at first). It gets one V at the end of p2 and the second V at the end of p1.

Comment: "p1 is the only process that can do work. It doubles a (== 4) then unblocks S3. It cannot continue because S2 is 0 again." isnt here S3=1?

Comment: It's 1 or 0 depending on whether p2 has already done V(S3) or not, as well as whether p3 has already done its first P(S3) or not. But in the end the result is always the same: p2 runs first -- because it can. p1 runs second because it waits on the end of p2. p3 runs last because it waits on the end of both p2 and p1.

Comment: thank you  very much @jods for your time in explaining this exercise